# Adding partitions to dual boot on Windows

Tags: installation, partitioning, dual-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windows 7 on an HP mini 210 netbook. I have down loaded an iso image OK and got the installation program working but I am having problems with partitioning.

I want to keep my Windows installation intact so I am following the 'Other' installation route. I have managed to shrink the main Windows partition down to 50GB leaving 250GB free space but I can't find a way of adding any extra partitions for Ubuntu. The free space gets listed by the installer as 'unusable' but on the graphic at the top its called 'free space'. If I select this and click 'Install Now' I get an error message: 'No root file system is defined'. I have tried clicking the Add, Change Delete and New Partition table buttons with the unusable partition selected and nothing happens. How do I define a root mount point when I do not have any Linux partitions?

Comment: More information is needed to see why this is happening. My guess is that you already have 4 primary partitions which is the maximum number of primary partitions. You would have to delete one of them and make an extended partition. Then you would be able to add more partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the Something else (advanced) option.  This option is used to create a /home partition.

> With the "free space" entry selected, click on the "Add" button. In
>   the new window, type for example 4096 in the "New partition size in
>   megabytes" field and select the "swap area" option from the "Use as:"
>   drop down list. Click the OK button and, in a few seconds, you'll
>   notice a "swap" line with the specified size;
>
> - With the "free space" line selected, click on the "Add" button. In the new window, select the "Primary" option, type a value between
>     30,000 and 50,000 (or whatever space you have left on the drive) in
>     the "New partition size in megabytes" field and select /home as the
>     "Mount point." Click the OK button and, in a few seconds, you'll
>     notice an "ext4 /home" line with the specified size;
> - With the "free space" entry selected, click on the "Add" button. In the new window, select the "Primary" option, type a value between
>     10,000 and 50,000 in the "New partition size in megabytes" field and
>     select / as the "Mount point." Click the OK button and, in a few
>     seconds, you'll notice an "ext4 /" line with the specified size.

OR

You can use [Windows installer for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) which enables you from installing Ubuntu from within windows.

Source: http://www.e-linux.it/news_detail/installing-ubuntu-1104